# How to add xeyes to the taskbar

Tags: x11, gnome2

Hoping my question is not regarded as silly, I would like to know how, if possible, I can attach the `xeyes` utility to the task bar. I do not simply want an icon on the task bar for launching `xeyes`, but rather have the animated eyes appear on the taskbar and not in a separate window. I'm fairly sure I had it this way on a debian distribution about 10 years ago. I am currently running squeeze and my desktop environment is GNOME 2.30.2.

Comment: What desktop environment or window manager and what taskbar application (if it isn't part of the DE/WM) are you running?

Comment: @Gilles Sorry for my late reply. I am running GNOME version 2.30.2. I do not think I have changed the taskbar/panel application, so it should be the default; don't know what it's called though.

Answer (score 1):

`xeyes` doesn't know how to embed itself in another window like the taskbar - GNOME 2.x included a `geyes` applet in the [gnome-applets](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeApplets) set that could do that, which is probably what you remember.

Comment: I seem to remember some window managers coming with "panels" which could swallow any window — AfterStep or Window Maker maybe?

Comment: Ah yes, it might be geyes. I'll check it out!